# Problem with class definitions in C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a class defined in the file `board.H`:

```
class Board
{
private:
    ...

public:
    ...
};
```

and in another class, I want to have a member that is a pointer to a `Board` object:

```
#include "board.H"

class Bear
{
private:
    Board* board;
    ...
public:
    ...
};
```

When I try to compile it (using g++ in linux) I get the following error:

```
bear.H:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Board' with no type
bear.H:15: error: expected `;' before '*' token
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your Board class definition inside a namespace?

Comment: I suspect the error lies in the part of the code you have clipped.

Comment: How are you compiling this? I see no problem with your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Common problem. You probably have a `#include "bear.H"` line in your "board.H" file or in a file included by "board.H".

So when you include "bear.H" into "board.H", the "bear.H" file is processed and tries to include "board.H", but that file is already being processed so the header guard of "bear.H" won't include the content another time. But then "bear.H" is processed without a leading "Board" class definition.

Comment: @Iiya Melamed I recommend that you make a new question for that. But as a hint - try to not depend on the definition of class Bear in "board.H". For example a "Bear*" doesn't need the definition of class "Bear", but only a forward declaration like "class Bear;". Then you don't need to include the "bear.H" header. Same goes for "void f(Bear b);" (but not "void f(Bear b) { }") and "Bear&".

Comment: Compiler directives. By wrapping your classes with the #ifndef, #define, #endif directives found at the following address, the compiler should only try to compile each class once: http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/ifndef.html

Comment: I love how circular dependency error messages like this are so ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Check the namespace.
If `Board` is in a different namespace than `Bear`, you need to add in Bear.h:

```
using <namespace>:: Board;
```